# Limit of an integral that resembles the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Calculate the following limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-2}}{1+ x^{n}}\cos(n\pi x) dx$$

I tried by broke down the integration from 0 to 1 and 1 to infinity. I am done with 0 to 1 part but I could not  figure out second part. I am thinking of applying Riemann lebesgue lemma.
is that work here?

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.I won't do that in future.@alexR but don't you have any idea on my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{x^{n-2}}{1+x^n}\cos (n\pi x)\, dx = \int_1^\infty\left (\frac{x^{n-2}}{1+x^n} - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)\cos (n\pi x)\, dx$$ $$ + \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\cos (n\pi x)\, dx.$$